# Overriding the default export button click event in crystal report viewer Print UI fdialog

Tags: pdf, printing, crystal-reports, export, window

I am new to crystal report anyway currently in the learning mode. When the default print icon in the tool bar is clicked the print UI dialog appears allowing us to select export format.

Once pdf format is selected and export button is clicked the pdf is exported with the report name and saved in my PC.

However my requirement is not to export the pdf but open in the same web page(window) without saving the pdf file. How can I override the default behavior of the export button?

I have gone through the allinone.js file provided by crystal reportviewer and identified some functions such as printSubmitted, _onPrint,_onSubmitPrintPdf but overriding them seems very complex.

Is there any simple method to override this default behaviour of the export button in the print UI dialog of the crystal report viewer?